# PHP - display database values on every content box in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/user/Michael" class="thumb-sm pull-left m-r-sm">
        <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8b7a9ba3cbf958009080f6da12a55029?&d=mm&r=g?&d=mm&r=g&s=215" class="img-circle">
    </a>
    <a href="user/Michael" class="clear">
        <strong class="block">
<?php include '/includes/connection.php';?>
<?php echo  $products['Title'] ; ?>
</strong>
        <?php include '/includes/connection.php';?>
<small><?php echo  $products['Followers'] ; ?> Followers </small>
</a>
</li>


<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/user/Steven" class="thumb-sm pull-left m-r-sm">
        <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a5fb2decd550cdf33cbb8ce7566ba772?&d=mm&r=g?&d=mm&r=g&s=215" class="img-circle">
    </a>
    <a href="/user/Steven" class="clear">
        <strong class="block">
    <?php include '/includes/connection.php';?>
<?php echo  $products['Title'] ; ?>
</strong>
        <small><?php echo  $products['Followers'] ; ?> Followers</small>
    </a>
</li>
```

do i need to manually insert  for every content?
I have over 100 contents how can i automatically insert in every line like content 1 display row 1 followers and content box 2 display row 2 followers and so on

Comment: have you tried using loops? `while, foreach, etc.`

Comment: The answer to your question is a clear: No. And: You do that by programming. And here is some hint: Do not copy and paste. Do not duplicate code.

Comment: @VaroStudio sorry mate, as your question stands, it seems we cannot answer this question on our side. we don't even know what `<?php include '/includes/connection.php';?>` does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to make a loop within the code. This means you have to generate all content from out of the database or it's not gonna work. Let me show you an example:

```
<ul>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT ProjectId, ProjectTitel, ProjectExpertise 
          FROM project"; 
    $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1,$ProjectId,$ProjectTitel,$ProjectExpertise);
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)){              
?>                    
    <li class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-offset="30" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="0.15s">
        <a href="inc/elements/project.php?id=<?php echo $ProjectId; ?>" class="meer">
            <img src="img/portfolio/<?php echo $ProjectId; ?>/thumbnail/1.jpg" alt="<?php echo $ProjectTitel; ?> project">
            <div class="project-info">
                <div class="project-details">
                    <h5 class="witte-text blauwe-streep-onder">
                        <?php echo $ProjectTitel; ?>
                    </h5>
                    <div class="details witte-text">   
                        <?php echo $ProjectExpertise; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php 
    } 
?>
</ul>
```

I start an UL outside of the PHP code and then I start my PHP query, as you see, i select the items i need from the database. Here i create a while loop and run through my setup of the list element. As you see, i use my items within the project id link (the link is an ajax call to another page), the thumbnail needed to show the picture, the title and the expertise i used.

In your case,  the while loop you need requires more than just the the title and followers. I think you need as well an userid / username so you can take in account which user it is. Your loop would now proces all on the same user, since its staticly defined in your code. Also the avatar picture is staticly defined. Let me try to resolve some for you.

```
<?php
    include '/includes/connection.php';

    $sql = "SELECT products.title, products.followers
          FROM products"; // as example query 
    $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1,$title, $followers);
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)){      
?>
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/user/Michael" class="thumb-sm pull-left m-r-sm">  <!--  make the username also to be pulled out of a database. -->
        <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8b7a9ba3cbf958009080f6da12a55029?&d=mm&r=g?&d=mm&r=g&s=215" class="img-circle"> 
    </a> <!-- you should save the avatar link into a database as well -->
    <a href="user/Michael" class="clear">  <!--  make the username also to be pulled out of a database. -->
        <strong class="block">
            <?php echo  $title; ?>
        </strong>
        <small>
            <?php echo $followers; ?> 
            Followers 
        </small>
     </a>
</li>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

This as example. As you see, i added notitions behind some code, to explain this should also be dynamic, since it will help you  Remember. being a programmer is to find shortcuts on how you display your information. Code that repeats itself constantly with a changing variable should always be looped, to make sure you dont type unneccesairy code.

Since I dont know how your database is made, i can only guess, Michaels name is probably linked to an ID in the same table your products are, which you can use then in to pull out of the database, by searching in your user table. I hope I make sense here. For instance, your `products.userid` should be as well in your user table as `user.userid`. Most likely the userid will have a name linked to it in the user table.

```
    $sql = "SELECT products.title, products.followers, products.userid, user.userid, user.username
            FROM products, user
            WHERE user.userid = product.userid";
```

So now you have in each row as well the name of the person of who's title it is. And that you can echo out again in the code i put up. (make sure you bind the result in the same order as you pulled them up)

Writing code is all about making it easier to display your information. `Loops` is and stays the keyword here, as NadirDev explains.

I hope I helped you getting on the right track.

Comment: Best answers! Well done and thank you for giving such clear explanations